# Vuejs routing working only partially.

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My App works just fine, if I put routes without childrens (nesting) but I tried to nest it just now and converted my routes to this: in `routes.js`

```
import alphabetsPage from './components/views/pages/alphabets.vue'
import dictionaryPage from './components/views/pages/dictionary.vue'
import numbersPage from './components/views/pages/numbers.vue'

import LayoutView from './components/views/Layout.vue'

const routes = [{

  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: LayoutView,
    children: [{
        path: 'basic',
        name: 'Basic',
        component: alphabetsPage,
          children: [{
            path: 'alphabets',
            name: 'Aphabets',
            component: alphabetsPage           
          },
          {
            path: 'numbers',
            name: 'Numbers',
            component: numbersPage           
          }]
    }]
}]

export default routes
```

If I go to `/` or click on route `<router-link to="/basic/alphabets"  tag="li"><a>numbers</a></router-link>` I can see the `alphabetsPage` component, however if I go click on `<router-link to="/basic/numbers"  tag="li"><a>numbers</a></router-link>` the route doesn't work. I have a `numbersPage` componet working.

This must be from the routes, because, if I don't use children and just define the path in routes as `/basic/numbers` or `/basic/alphabets` it works.

Comment: What if you change the "numbers" path to " /basic/alphabets/numbers"? If I understand your setup, it appears numbers is a child of alphabets which is a child of basic? Maybe a plunkr setup would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children should be shown somewhere.

Your alphabetsPage do not have  in template

```
const alphabetsPage = {
    template: '<div>/basic/alphabets <router-view></router-view></div>'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fvL1xwc/